# How to import existing project into current Xcode Project (Yelp into project)

Tags: ios, swift, yelp

I am currently trying to integrate the yelp api into my iPhone application. On yelp's developer website, they allow you to use their existing code samples. So i downloaded their Objective-C code and i put the .xcodeproj file under the main file 
[image: Like this]

I want to know how I can actually use the YelpAPISample project in my own project... and i'm clueless as to how.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't use their project in your project. You use their _code_ in your project.

Comment: So I just copy and paste all the files into my project file?

Comment: When I add the existing files into my project, I get over 28 build errors... Most having to do with Arc Semantics.. How do I get around this?